# 500 internal server error when editing files on ubuntu server(No Module named Django)

Tags: python, django, linux, apache, devops

I had my website running normally not until I made a few changes in the views.py and one of the templates file. Then I had this Werid error, "500 Internal Server Error", and when I changed the error logs. I saw the error.

Error Logs

````
(venv) root@vps-e47d7ac6:/home/ubuntu/app# sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Tue Jan 26 07:40:03.581363 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 18182:tid 140673103349504] [remote 197.210.227.43:50689] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jan 26 07:40:03.581405 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 18182:tid 140673103349504] [remote 197.210.227.43:50689]   File "/var/www/app/station/asgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Tue Jan 26 07:40:03.581414 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 18182:tid 140673103349504] [remote 197.210.227.43:50689]     from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
[Tue Jan 26 07:40:03.581446 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 18182:tid 140673103349504] [remote 197.210.227.43:50689] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[Tue Jan 26 07:40:04.348655 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 18182:tid 140673220962048] [remote 197.210.54.234:55809] mod_wsgi (pid=18182): Target WSGI script '/var/www/app/station/asgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Jan 26 07:40:04.348789 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 18182:tid 140673220962048] [remote 197.210.54.234:55809] mod_wsgi (pid=18182): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/app/station/asgi.py'.
[Tue Jan 26 07:40:04.348939 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 18182:tid 140673220962048] [remote 197.210.54.234:55809] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jan 26 07:40:04.348978 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 18182:tid 140673220962048] [remote 197.210.54.234:55809]   File "/var/www/app/station/asgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Tue Jan 26 07:40:04.348987 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 18182:tid 140673220962048] [remote 197.210.54.234:55809]     from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
[Tue Jan 26 07:40:04.349017 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 18182:tid 140673220962048] [remote 197.210.54.234:55809] ImportError: No module named 'django'

I noticed that the version of pip i was using is very old around 8.9.0, so i upgraded it to the laste one 20.0.2 but i was not able to use pip again to install packages, what could be wrong please

I ran the following commands to fix my pip issue ```sudo apt update```, ```sudo apt install python-pip``` and when i ran the ```pip --version``` I got the error below.
````

(venv) root@vps-e47d7ac6:/home/ubuntu/app# pip install -r requirements.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/pip", line 7, in 
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `python -m pip install django` try this

Comment: `pip freeze` Does it show Django in the output? Is Django present in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: @coderboy, It clearly says django is not installed. May be it is missing in requirements.txt.
Hoping this link will guide you in setting up django
[Django-Install](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Django is present in the requirements.txt file and in fact I am able to run the django-admin command which shows django is present

Comment: Ok, then can you check if the python environment you are using has django in it? If not please install it there or use a python environment that has django and all other tools!

Comment: @SidharthMA 
Please check the updated question, I think I am making some progress